# Changing end date time programmatically

Tags: angular, date, datepicker, datetimepicker, angular7

I want to change my min date at runtime.

```
    <input class="form-control" id="endDateTime" [owlDateTime]="endDateTime" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="endDateTime"
                  [min]='endDateTimePickerConfig.min' placeholder="End Date Time" formControlName="endDateTime">
                <owl-date-time #endDateTime [firstDayOfWeek]='endDateTimePickerConfig.firstDayOfWeek'
                  [hour12Timer]='endDateTimePickerConfig.hour12Timer'></owl-date-time>

  public startDateTimePickerConfig = {
    min: new Date(),
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    hour12Timer: true
  };

  public endDateTimePickerConfig = Object.assign({}, this.startDateTimePickerConfig);;

    constructor() {
          this.initializeEndDate(this.startDateTimePickerConfig.min);
        }

      private initializeEndDate(startDateTime: Date): void {
        this.endDateTimePickerConfig.min = this.incrementMinutes(this.endDateTimePickerConfig.min, 1);
      }

    private incrementMinutes(date: Date, minutes: number): Date {
        return new Date(date.getFullYear(),
          date.getMonth(),
          date.getDate(),
          date.getHours(),
          date.getMinutes() + minutes,
          date.getSeconds(),
          date.getMilliseconds());
      }
```

However when the min date in the typescript changes, the UI refreshes only the select box https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MvME.png, but after clicking set, the input gets filled with the old minutes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/imhja.png This is some strange behavior. Any suggestions?
PS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are changing the value from an attribute from an object (this.endDateTimePickerConfig.min).
Try create a new 'plain' attribute and set it to the [min] property.

Example:

```
.ts
minEndDateTimePickerConfig: Number;
...
private initializeEndDate(startDateTime: Date): void {
   this.minEndDateTimePickerConfig = this.incrementMinutes(this.minEndDateTimePickerConfig, 1);
}

.html
[min]='minEndDateTimePickerConfig'
```

Comment: Nop, even tried new Date(new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes()+1)) to be sure it doesn't have to do something with the lazy initialization and still didn't work. Seems that the bug happens when your open the select box and click immediately "Set" without changing the time